# Use combobox value as query value (VC# 2k8 / ADO SQLITE)

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

I'm a newbie in VC# and ADO SQLITE...

I'm trying to change the content of a combobox according to the value present in another one...

My problem is here :

```
SQLiteCommand cmd3 = new SQLiteCommand("select distinct(ACTION) from ACTION_LIST where CATEGORY='comboBox1.text'", conn2);
```

What to use to do the job ? Here 'comboBox1.text' is see as a sentence not a variable...

Here is the code :

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn1 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = Data\MRIS_DB_MASTER"))
            {
                conn1.Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd2 = new SQLiteCommand("select distinct(CATEGORY) from ACTION_LIST", conn1);
                SQLiteDataAdapter adapter1 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd2);
                DataTable tbl1 = new DataTable();
                adapter1.Fill(tbl1);
                comboBox1.DataSource = tbl1;
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CATEGORY";
                adapter1.Dispose();
                cmd2.Dispose();
            }

            using (SQLiteConnection conn2 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = Data\MRIS_DB_MASTER"))
            {
                conn2.Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd3 = new SQLiteCommand("select distinct(ACTION) from ACTION_LIST where CATEGORY='comboBox1.text'", conn2);
                SQLiteDataAdapter adapter2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd3);
                DataTable tbl2 = new DataTable();
                adapter2.Fill(tbl2);
                comboBox2.DataSource = tbl2;
                comboBox2.DisplayMember = "ACTION";
                adapter2.Dispose();
                cmd3.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Thanks

regards

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter`.  Try this out.  (I may have some syntax wrong because I'm not able to test this right now...but it should be similar)

From your code:

```
    SQLiteCommand cmd3 = new SQLiteCommand("select distinct(ACTION) from ACTION_LIST where CATEGORY=@category", conn2);
cmd3.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@category",comboBox1.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

comboBox1.Text is the label of the combobox, you need comboBox1.SelectedValue.  You also   need to do what aaron says and add a parameter.

Comment: If you say so, but be aware that you are querying based on the label of the combobox not on the value the user has selected.